# Generalized Bottom up Parser Combinators in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators, attoparsec

I am wondered why there is no generalized parser combinators for Bottom-up parsing in Haskell like a Parsec combinators for top down parsing. 
( I could find some research work went during 2004 but nothing after 
https://haskell-functional-parsing.googlecode.com/files/Ljunglof-2002a.pdf
http://www.di.ubi.pt/~jpf/Site/Publications_files/technicalReport.pdf )

Is there any specific reason for not achieving it?

Answer (score 12):

This is because of referential transparency. Just as no function can tell the difference between

```
let x = 1:x
let x = 1:1:1:x
let x = 1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:...  -- if this were writeable
```

no function can tell the difference between a grammar which is a finite graph and a grammar which is an infinite tree.  Bottom-up parsing algorithms need to be able to see the grammar as a graph, in order to enumerate all the possible parsing states.

The fact that top-down parsers see their input as infinite trees allows them to be more powerful, since the tree could be computationally more complex than any graph could be; for example,

```
numSequence n = string (show n) *> option () (numSequence (n+1))
```

accepts any finite ascending sequence of numbers starting at `n`.  This has infinitely many different parsing states.  (It might be possible to represent this in a context-free way, but it would be tricky and require more understanding of the code than a parsing library is capable of, I think)

A bottom up combinator library *could* be written, though it is a bit ugly, by requiring all parsers to be "labelled" in such a way that

- the same label always refers to the same parser, and
- there is only a finite set of labels

at which point it begins to look a lot more like a traditional specification of a grammar than a combinatory specification.  However, it could still be nice; you would only have to label recursive productions, which would rule out any infinitely-large rules such as `numSequence`.

Comment: There are other approaches than manually labeling, by the way. C.f. [data-reify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify) which transforms a recursive DSL into a graph representation for you. See also [this paper](https://ku-fpg.github.io/files/Gill-09-TypeSafeReification.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

As luqui's answer indicates a bottom-up parser *combinator* library is not a realistic.  On the chance that someone gets to this page just looking for haskell's bottom up parser *generator*, what you are looking for is called [the Happy parser generator](http://www.haskell.org/happy/).  It is like `yacc` for haskell.

Answer (score 4):

As luqui said above: Haskell's treatment of recursive parser definitions does not permit the definition of bottom-up parsing libraries. Bottom-up parsing libraries are possible though if you represent recursive grammars differently. With apologies for the self-promotion, one (research) parser library that uses such an approach is [grammar-combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/grammar-combinators). It implements a grammar transformation called the uniform Paull transformation that can be combined with the top-down parser algorithm to obtain a bottom-up parser for the original grammar.

Answer (score 1):

@luqui essentially says, that there are cases in which sharing is unobservable. However, it's not the case in general: many approaches to observable sharing exist. E.g. http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~andygill/papers/reifyGraph.pdf mentions a few different methods to achieve observable sharing and proposes its own new method:

> This looping structure can be used for interpretation, but not for
>   further analysis, pretty printing, or general processing. The
>   challenge here, and the subject of this paper, is how to allow trees
>   extracted from Haskell hosted deep DSLs to have observable back-edges,
>   or more generally, observable sharing. This a well-understood problem,
>   with a number of standard solutions.

Note that the "ugly" solution of @liqui is mentioned by the paper under the name of *explicit labels*. The solution proposed by the paper is still "ugly" as it uses so called "stable names", but other solutions such as http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2012/graphs.pdf (which relies on PHOAS) may work.